# Add lines to a json file extracting key value pair using Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, multidimensional-array

**Issue:**

I have two lines in a raw json file which has several key value pairs. I'm trying to extract specific key value pairs for each line, append it to a dictionary and then dump the output as a new json file which has all the data I'm looking for -->

```
{
    "visitNumber": "151",
    "visitId": "1470083489",
    "visitStartTime": "1470083489",
    "date": "20160801",
    "totals": {
        "visits": "1",
        "hits": "3",
        "pageviews": "3",
        "timeOnSite": "529"
    },
    "device": {
        "browser": "Chrome",
        "browserVersion": "not available in demo dataset",
        "browserSize": "not available in demo dataset",
        "operatingSystem": "Windows",
        "operatingSystemVersion": "not available in demo dataset",
        "isMobile": false,
        "mobileDeviceBranding": "not available in demo dataset",
        "mobileDeviceModel": "not available in demo dataset",
        "mobileInputSelector": "not available in demo dataset",
        "mobileDeviceInfo": "not available in demo dataset",
        "mobileDeviceMarketingName": "not available in demo dataset",
        "flashVersion": "not available in demo dataset",
        "language": "not available in demo dataset",
        "screenColors": "not available in demo dataset",
        "screenResolution": "not available in demo dataset",
        "deviceCategory": "desktop"
    },
    "geoNetwork": {
        "continent": "Americas",
        "subContinent": "Northern America",
        "country": "United States",
        "region": "California",
        "metro": "San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA",
        "city": "San Jose",
        "cityId": "not available in demo dataset",
        "networkDomain": "unknown.unknown",
        "latitude": "not available in demo dataset",
        "longitude": "not available in demo dataset",
        "networkLocation": "not available in demo dataset"
    },
    "hits": [
        {
            "hitNumber": "1",
            "time": "0",
            "hour": "13",
            "minute": "31",
            "isInteraction": true,
            "isEntrance": true,
            "page": {
                "pagePath": "/home",
                "hostname": "shop.googlemerchandisestore.com",
                "pageTitle": "Home",
                "pagePathLevel1": "/home",
                "pagePathLevel2": "",
                "pagePathLevel3": "",
                "pagePathLevel4": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "hitNumber": "2",
            "time": "289206",
            "hour": "13",
            "minute": "36",
            "isInteraction": true,
            "page": {
                "pagePath": "/google+redesign/apparel/men++s/men++s+t+shirts",
                "hostname": "shop.googlemerchandisestore.com",
                "pageTitle": "Men's-T-Shirts",
                "pagePathLevel1": "/google+redesign/",
                "pagePathLevel2": "/apparel/",
                "pagePathLevel3": "/men++s/",
                "pagePathLevel4": "/men++s+t+shirts"
            }
        }
       ],
  }



{
    "visitNumber": "1",
    "visitId": "1470117657",
    "visitStartTime": "1470117657",
    "date": "20160801",
    "totals": {
        "visits": "1",
        "hits": "3",
        "pageviews": "3",
        "timeOnSite": "54",
        "newVisits": "1"
    },
    "device": {
        "browser": "Internet Explorer",
        "browserVersion": "not available in demo dataset",
        "browserSize": "not available in demo dataset",
        "operatingSystem": "Windows",
        "operatingSystemVersion": "not available in demo dataset",
        "isMobile": false,
        "mobileDeviceBranding": "not available in demo dataset",
        "mobileDeviceModel": "not available in demo dataset",
        "mobileInputSelector": "not available in demo dataset",
        "mobileDeviceInfo": "not available in demo dataset",
        "mobileDeviceMarketingName": "not available in demo dataset",
        "flashVersion": "not available in demo dataset",
        "language": "not available in demo dataset",
        "screenColors": "not available in demo dataset",
        "screenResolution": "not available in demo dataset",
        "deviceCategory": "desktop"
    },
    "geoNetwork": {
        "continent": "Americas",
        "subContinent": "Northern America",
        "country": "United States",
        "region": "not available in demo dataset",
        "metro": "not available in demo dataset",
        "city": "not available in demo dataset",
        "cityId": "not available in demo dataset",
        "networkDomain": "telia.net",
        "latitude": "not available in demo dataset",
        "longitude": "not available in demo dataset",
        "networkLocation": "not available in demo dataset"
    },
    "hits": [
        {
            "hitNumber": "1",
            "time": "0",
            "hour": "23",
            "minute": "0",
            "isInteraction": true,
            "isEntrance": true,
            "referer": "https://www.youtube.com/yt/about/",
            "page": {
                "pagePath": "/home",
                "hostname": "shop.googlemerchandisestore.com",
                "pageTitle": "Home",
                "pagePathLevel1": "/home",
                "pagePathLevel2": "",
                "pagePathLevel3": "",
                "pagePathLevel4": ""
            }
         }
       ]
}
```

I am trying to extract key value pairs and create another json file with the same format. To achieve this objective here is what I tried to **code**:

```
     import json
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

visits_dict = {}
hits_dict = {}

hits_array = []

with open(r"C:\Users\rparpani\Documents\Test.json") as f:
    for line in f:
        json_object = json.loads(line)

        #This code builds the visit dictionary
        visits_dict["full_visitor_id"] = json_object["fullVisitorId"]
        visits_dict["visit_id"] = json_object["visitId"]
        visits_dict["visit_number"] = json_object["visitNumber"]

        visit_StartTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(json_object["visitStartTime"])).isoformat()
        visits_dict["visit_start_time"] = visit_StartTime

        visits_dict["browser"] = json_object["device"].get('browser')
        visits_dict["country"] = json_object["geoNetwork"].get('country')

        print(visits_dict)

        visitstartTime_unixValue = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(json_object["visitStartTime"]))
        #print(visitstartTime_unixValue)

        #This code outputs the data to a visits.json file
        analyticsInfo_visitsOutput = open("C:\\Users\\rparpani\\Documents\\visits.json", "a")
        json.dump(visits_dict, analyticsInfo_visitsOutput)
        analyticsInfo_visitsOutput.write('\n')

        # hits_arraycount = int(json_object.get('totals').get('hits'))
        # print(hits_arraycount)

        #This code builds the hits dictionary
        for j in json_object["hits"]:
            #print(j.get('hitNumber'))
            hits_dict["hit_number"] = j.get('hitNumber')
            hits_dict["hit_type"] = j.get('type')

            hit_timeValue = int(j.get('time'))
            time_ms = timedelta(milliseconds=hit_timeValue)
            new_time = visitstartTime_unixValue + time_ms
            hits_dict["hit_timestamp"] = new_time.isoformat()

            hits_dict["page_path"] = j.get('page').get('pagePath')
            hits_dict["page_title"] = j.get('page').get('pageTitle')
            hits_dict["hostname"] = j.get('page').get('hostname')   
            
            print(hits_dict)
            

        
        #This code outputs the data to a visits.json file
            analyticsInfo_hitsOutput = open("C:\\Users\\rparpani\\Documents\\hits.json", "a")
            json.dump(hits_dict, analyticsInfo_hitsOutput)
            analyticsInfo_hitsOutput.write('\n')
```

The code gives me the output the way I expect with the correct key value pairs but I'm a bit lost about how to store the hit values in a list like the original input.

Can someone please give me suggestions on how to solve for this?

**Actual Output:**

```
    {'full_visitor_id': '8159312408158297118', 'visit_id': '1470083489', 'visit_number': '151', 'visit_start_time': '2016-08-01T15:31:29', 'browser': 'Chrome', 'country': 'United States'}
{'hit_number': '1', 'hit_type': 'PAGE', 'hit_timestamp': '2016-08-01T15:31:29', 'page_path': '/home', 'page_title': 'Home', 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com'}
{'hit_number': '2', 'hit_type': 'PAGE', 'hit_timestamp': '2016-08-01T15:36:18.206000', 'page_path': '/google+redesign/apparel/men++s/men++s+t+shirts', 'page_title': "Men's-T-Shirts", 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com'}
{'hit_number': '3', 'hit_type': 'PAGE', 'hit_timestamp': '2016-08-01T15:40:17.730000', 'page_path': '/google+redesign/office', 'page_title': 'Office', 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com'}
```

Expected Output:

```
{'full_visitor_id': '8159312408158297118', 'visit_id': '1470083489', 'visit_number': '151', 'visit_start_time': '2016-08-01T15:31:29', 'browser': 'Chrome', 'country': 'United States'}
{'hits':[{'hit_number': '1', 'hit_type': 'PAGE', 'hit_timestamp': '2016-08-01T15:31:29', 'page_path': '/home', 'page_title': 'Home', 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com'}
{'hit_number': '2', 'hit_type': 'PAGE', 'hit_timestamp': '2016-08-01T15:36:18.206000', 'page_path': '/google+redesign/apparel/men++s/men++s+t+shirts', 'page_title': "Men's-T-Shirts", 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com'}
{'hit_number': '3', 'hit_type': 'PAGE', 'hit_timestamp': '2016-08-01T15:40:17.730000', 'page_path': '/google+redesign/office', 'page_title': 'Office', 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com'}]}
```

Comment: I just need some help creating the hits dictionary with the format explained in the expected output

Comment: I solved the problem by creating an array and putting that in a dictionary. After it is put in the dictionary, you empty out the array before the loop is run again. This problem is now solved

Comment: Consider adding the answer as an answer not a comment, then accepting the answer